# Javascript time spent playing

Tags: javascript

How would I format the time being played by using a variable.
I need to store the current time spent playing by using a timer I would assume.
I will update the current time every-time paused is pressed.
How then would I format the variable into a readable format? 
What is the best way to do all of this, what timers? How?

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Make an effort to figure it out on your own first.  If you run into problems you cant solve, we're more than willing to help if you give us all the proper information

Comment: If you're only going to update/display the elapsed time in response to pausing you don't need timers, you just need to do some stuff with [the `Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). (Record the start time, subtract that from the current time when pause is pressed...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question doesn't give much details to help you.

But here are some links for javascript timers.

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/06/28/understanding-javascript-timers/

http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/

You may have a play/pause button. And trigger functions on pressing that button.
Try something using this information, when stuck in some problem, post what you tried, and people will help you.